# MYSQL Alternative to UNION for same table reusing same columns selected as new name

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to generate a result set from a table with effectively a unique/primary key as billyear, billmonth and type along with cost and consumption. So there could be 3 bill year and bill month identical entries but the type could be one of three values: E, W or NG.

I need to create a result set that has just one row per billyear and billmonth entry.

```
(
select month as billmonth, year as billyear, cost_estimate as eleccost, consumption_estimate as eleccons from tblbillforecast where buildingid=19 and type='E'
)
UNION  (
select month as billmonth, year as billyear, cost_estimate as gascost, consumption_estimate as gascons from tblbillforecast where buildingid=19 and type='NG'
)
UNION  (
select month as billmonth, year as billyear, cost_estimate as watercost, consumption_estimate as watercons from tblbillforecast where buildingid=19 and type='W'
)
```

This generates a result set with only billmonth, billyear, eleccost and eleccons columns. I've tried all kinds of solutions but the above example is the simplest to show where it's going wrong.

Additionally it still has 3 rows per billmonth/billyear unique combination instead of merging to one.

UPDATE:
Sample data
[image]

```
SELECT month AS billmonth,
  year AS billyear,
  SUM(CASE type WHEN 'E' THEN cost_estimate END) AS eleccost,
  SUM(CASE type WHEN 'NG' THEN cost_estimate END) AS gascost,
  SUM(CASE type WHEN 'W' THEN cost_estimate END) AS watercost
FROM tblbillforecast
WHERE buildingid=19
GROUP BY billmonth, billyear;
```

Result:
[image]

Expected result, eg:

year | month | eleccost | gascost | watercost

2018 | 1 | 32800 | 4460 | 4750

Comment: All aliases except ones in the most first subquery are always ignored. Use conditional aggregation.

Comment: I suggest instead of posting screenshots of data (which is [discouraged in the Stack Overflow guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)), you should create a reproducible test case on https://dbfiddle.uk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick bit of guidance on various data shaping operations in SQL:

- JOIN - makes resultsets wider (more columns) by bringing together tables/resultsets in a side-by-side fashion generating output rows that have all the columns of the two input column sets
- SELECT - typically makes resultsets narrower by allowing you to specify which columns you're interested in and which you are not; by not mentioning an available column it disappears meaning you output fewer columns
- UNION - makes resultsets taller (more rows) by bringing together resultsets and outputting one on top of the other. Because columns always have a fixed data type and one name, you must have the same number of and type of, and order of columns
- WHERE - makes resultsets shorter (fewer rows) by allowing you to specify truth based filters that exclude rows

It's not hard and fast; you can use select to create more columns too, but just in a very rudimentary sense these concepts hold true - JOIN to widen, UNION for taller, SELECT for narrower and WHERE for shorter. All the work you do with SQL is a data shaping exercise; you're either paring a rectangular block of data down or extending it, and in either a vertical or horizontal direction (or a mix).

I'm not going to get into grouping because that mixes rows up, and isn't something you tried in the question.. The reason for me writing this out was purely because you'd attempted to use a UNION (height-increasing) operation when you actually wanted a *widen* which, regardless of how it is done (JOIN or as per Bill's answer a SELECT+GROUP, which is valid, but relies on the "mixes rows up" aspect of grouping), specifically **isn't done** with a UNION. Union only makes stuff taller.

To give an example of how it might be done in an alternative way to Bill's approach, this task of yours has one huge table that is "too tall" - it uses 3 rows where 1 would do, if only it were a *bit wider*. That is to say if only there were 3 columns for electric/gas/water then we wouldn't need 3 rows with 1 utility in each.

Of course, we have this "one utility per row" because *it is very flexible*. Database tables don't have varying numbers of columns but they DO have varying numbers of rows. If a new bill type came along tomorrow - internet - no table changes are needed to accommodate it; add a new type I, and away you go, adding another row. We now store 4 rows of 1 utility where 1 row with 4 columns would do, but crucially we didn't have to change the table structure. We could have infinite different kinds of bills, and not need infinite columns because we can already have infinite rows

So you want to reshape your data from 4-rows-by-1-column to 1-row-by-4-columns. It *could* be solved as :

- narrow the table to just year,month,building,type,cost AND shorten it to just electricity
- separately narrow the table to just year,month,building,type,cost AND shorten it to just gas
- separately narrow the table to just year,month,building,type,cost AND shorten it to just water
- join (widening) all these newly created result sets , then narrow to remove the repeated year,month,building,type columns

That would look like:

```
SELECT e.year, e.month, e.building, e.cost, g.cost, w.cost 
FROM
  (SELECT year,month,building,cost FROM t WHERE type = 'E') e

  JOIN
  (SELECT year,month,building,cost FROM t WHERE type = 'NG') g
  ON
    e.year = g.year AND e.month = g.month AND e.building = g.building
  
  JOIN
  (SELECT year,month,building,cost FROM t WHERE type = 'W') w
  ON
    e.year = w.year AND e.month = w.month AND e.building = w.building

WHERE
  e.building = 19
```

You can see clearly the 3 narrowing-and-shortening operations that pick out "just the gas", "just the electric", and "just the water" - they're the `(SELECT year,month,building,cost FROM t WHERE type = 'NG')` and that's what reduces the height of the original table, making it three times shorter than it was in each case. If we had 999 rows X 5 cols in the big table it goes to 3 sets of 333 x 5 rows each

You can see that we then JOIN these together to widen the results - our e.g 3 sets of 333 x 5 rows each widens to 333 x 15 when JOINed..

Then went from 333x15 down to 333 X 7 when SELECTed to ditch the repeated columns

It's likely not perfect (I'd perhaps left join all 3 onto a 4th set of numbers that are just the common columns in case some utilities aren't present for a particular month), and perhaps some people will come along complaining that it's less performant because it hits the table 3 times.. All that is accessory to the point I'm making about SQL being an exercise in reshaping data - tables are the starting blocks of data and you cut them up narrower and shorter, then stick them together side by side, or on top of each other and that becomes your new data block that's maybe wider, higher, both.. In any case it's definitely a different shape to what you started with. And then you can cut and shape again, and again..

Go with Bill's conditional agg (though this way would be fine if there is one row per building/year/month) but take away a stronger notion about *in what direction* these common operations (SELECT/JOIN/WHERE/UNION) reshape your data

---

Footnote about Bill's conditional aggregation (I know I said I wouldn't talk about it but it might make more sense to now). If you have:

```
Type, Cost
E, 123
NG, 456
W, 789
```

And you do a

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN Type = 'E' THEN Cost END as CostE,
  CASE WHEN Type = 'NG' THEN Cost END as CostG,
  CASE WHEN Type = 'W' THEN Cost END as CostW
...
```

It spreads the data out over more columns - the data has "gone from vertical to diagonal"

```
CostE, CostNG, CostW
123, NULL, NULL
NULL, 456, NULL
NULL, NULL, 789
```

But it's still too tall. If you then run a GROUP BY, which *mixes rows up* and ask for e.g. just the MAX from each column, then all the NULLs will disappear (because there is a non null somewhere in the column, and NULL is lost if there is a non null, no matter what you're doing) and the rows collapse, mixing together, into one:

```
CostE, CostNG, CostW
123, 456, 789
```

The data has pivoted round from being vertical, to being horizontal - another data shaping. It was pulled wider, and squashed flatter

Comment: Excellent advice/lesson! To handle ensuring all year+month combinations were included I started with a SELECT ( union all tables ) LEFT JOIN to the main answer above.

Comment: Makes sense to me; `select distinct year, month from t` And then left join into that as it's guaranteed to have all variations of values :)

Answer (score 2):

This is behaving correctly. An SQL query result set has one name per column, and this name applies to all the rows. So if you try to rename the column in the second or subsequent queries of the UNION, those new names are ignored. The name of the column is determined only by the first query of the UNION.

> Additionally it still has 3 rows per billmonth/billyear unique combination instead of merging to one.

That's also correct behavior, according to the query you tried. UNION does not merge multiple rows into one, it only appends sets of rows.

As Akina hinted in the comments above, you may use multiple columns:

```
SELECT month AS billmonth,
  year AS billyear,
  SUM(CASE type WHEN 'E' THEN cost_estimate END) AS eleccost,
  SUM(CASE type WHEN 'NG' THEN cost_estimate END) AS gascost,
  SUM(CASE type WHEN 'W' THEN cost_estimate END) AS watercost
FROM tblbillforecast
WHERE buildingid=19
GROUP BY billmonth, billyear;
```

This uses `GROUP BY` to "merge" rows together, so you get one row in the result per month/year.

Comment: This is much closer! I'm stuck still on using SUM though. I edited my question to include sample data and the result of using your example. I tried removing SUM (grouping ignored NG and W all null) and adding a limit 1 but that wasn't allowed.

Comment: How many rows in the table per building/year/month ? Bill's query is correct, but if you have multiple rows (that you haven't shown us) for a particular building/year/month combo then SUM will aggregate them all. If you don't understand what I'm asking, show us the result of `select * from tblbillforecast where buildingid = 19 and billyear = 2018 and billmonth = 1`

Comment: Can you show the result of `SELECT * FROM tblbillforecast WHERE buildingid=19 AND year=2018 AND month=1;` I suspect your table has more than one row that matches those conditions. (simulpost with the comment edit by Caius Jard)

Comment: Yes, I showed the sample data in my last edit. There would be 3 rows per year+month, one for each of the 3 types E,NG,W. The primary key is year/month/type